# Blueimp gallery - video from YouTube

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube, blueimp

I'm struggling with blueimp video player implementation on my website. I've done photo gallery, but I don't get how to enable videos from Youtube. 

 I found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800798/blueimp-gallery-with-both-images-and-youtube-video) topic and tried to use the code from there, but with no satisfying result.

 I'm building website on BootStrap framework.

I can't send you my code, because it's really messy now as I tried a lot of different possibilities I could think of.

When I started with photo gallery I opened up BlueImp's documentation and followed the "SETUP" steps. But that was for photos only. When I scrolled down to [VIDEO](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md#html5-video-player) section a ran into a problem. Because I don't know what to do with that piece of code. I figured out to put CAROUSEL version of the player, with all control buttons, but I can't connect it to any of YouTube video. [Screenshot of what I've got right now when I open the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Os627.png)

 There is no video, just blank player. 

 The thing is, I would like you to  tell me step by step what to do so I could understand it, I would really appriciate it as I really can't figure it out myself (I'm not website coder and currently I don't have much time for learning this stuff, but I promised my brother I will do it for him).

 Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've included the reference to the BlueImp YouTube JS.

It's not clear from the Blueimp setup on GitHub but you need to include the reference to the YouTube JS.

```
<script src="js/blueimp-gallery-youtube.js"></script>
```

Then you need a link with the following tags inside you anchor:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={yourvideolink}"
title="Video title text"
type="text/html"
data-youtube="{yourvideolink}"
data-poster="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{yourvideolink}/0.jpg"
data-gallery></a>
```

Replace the {yourvideolink} with the video id YouTube gives you from the share code.

That got me working after two days of puzzling.